# Using a Series in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, series, normal-distribution, variance

I have 10,000 data in column A that hold values for a normal distribution; I have to estimate the variance using the series

[series here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/2/4/02470239549e54096ce7be4293f37aa3.png)

I've already estimated the sample mean x̄
, but my question is how do I apply the series to all the cells in a column? Or if I have to split it up into parts (subtraction, then squaring, then summation) how do I change the data in each cell by the same amount?